# How to split and separate root directory and sub directories from the path in python

Tags: python, list, replace, split, path

Paths in the list:

```
pathlist=[3rdParty\metrics-server\Dockerfile,
3rdParty\node-problem-detector\Dockerfile,
3rdParty\oci-cloud\test\Dockerfile,
static-analysis\python-dependency-check\tests\unit\test_dockerfiles\real\kibana\Dockerfile]
```

I have tried

```
for path in pathlist:
    p=path.parent  #removes file name from path
    p=p.split('\', 1)
```

even tried converting path to raw string like but did not worked, even I couldn't replace '/' with any other character

Expected output:

```
['3rdParty','metrics-server']
['3rdParty','node-problem-detector']
['3rdParty','oci-cloud\test']
['static-analysis', 'python-dependency-check\tests\unit\test_dockerfiles\real\kibana']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), you should be doing something like the following.

This uses the [`.parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) attribute to do the splitting of `path.parent` into components reliably. You shouldn't assume the directory separator.

Then, reconstruct the rest of the path by passing it back to [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path).

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in pathlist:
    parts = path.parent.parts
    res = [parts[0], str(Path(*parts[1:]))]
    print(res)
```

In the case of Windows, this should give you the desired output:

```
['3rdParty', 'metrics-server']
['3rdParty', 'node-problem-detector']
['3rdParty', 'oci-cloud\test']
['static-analysis', 'python-dependency-check\tests\unit\test_dockerfiles\real\kibana']
```

In the case of *NIX, you will get this:

```
['3rdParty', 'metrics-server']
['3rdParty', 'node-problem-detector']
['3rdParty', 'oci-cloud/test']
['static-analysis', 'python-dependency-check/tests/unit/test_dockerfiles/real/kibana']
```